# Flutter write script for to write code in project

Tags: flutter, file, dart

I have a file inside my Flutter-project. A simple `.dart` file which looks like this:

```
class EnLanguage implements BaseLanguage {
  @override
  Map<String, String> get language => {'test': 'test'};
}
```

Now my goal is that I write I script which I by executing goes through all my Project-files, searches for specific `Strings` ( the ones with a `.tr` ending) and adds it to the map in the class above (`key` and `value` are the same).

I couldn't find any way to achieve this. How does a simple script looks like that can write inside my project files? Im not asking for the whole logic, I just need a start. I couldn't find anything..

Comment: Why not use _actual_ localisation features from Flutter? https://docs.flutter.dev/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization

Comment: @MartinBean I don't really like this approach... I am trying to find a way without needing a context. But thats another question

Comment: But that’s what Flutter is based around: widgets and contexts. It’s literally one of the building blocks of Flutter apps.

Comment: @MartinBean I am aware of that. But that is not what the question is about

Comment: You can write a python script for this purpose. I'll suggest, instead of modifying that source code from script. Add that map to a separate file and read it from there.

Comment: No. Your question seems to be, “How can I write _more_ code because I'm not using a language and library the way it's intended to be used.“ You’re literally asking how to write code to solve a problem you’ve entirely created for yourself.

Comment: @MartinBean chill :D this is not what the question is about.  I appreciate your help. I am well aware how the "intended" way works. I worked with that, but in my opinion that is not the easiest way to get it done. I am just trying some other things. Thats why I asked the question

Comment: @MidhunMP That seems like a good.will probably go with that way

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the package [dcli](https://pub.dev/packages/dcli) and specifically the `pack` command. It does a chunk of what you need.

Not quite certain what you mean by strings ending with a .tr.

But to process each script.

```
var project = DartProject.self.pathToPackage;

find('*.dart', workingDirectory: project)
.forEach((script) {
    read(script). forEach((line) {
  If (line. contains('.tr'))
  {
   Extract line...
   Write to generated file..
}
```